# How to update @Published variable in ViewModel from network code?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this (firing off 3 simultaneous network calls)

```
class GenerationViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var fetching1:Bool = false
  @Published var fetching2:Bool = false
  @Published var fetching3:Bool = false

  func go() {  
      let service1 = Service(??)  //what to pass here so that Service can update fetching1 only
      let service2 = Service(??) //what to pass here so that Service can update fetching2 only
      let service3 = Service(??) //what to pass here so that Service can update fetching3 only
  }
}
```

How do I update the published variables from another class?

Comment: Multiple options. The two that come to mind first are: pass a closure or pass a binding.

Comment: Can you provide a binding example?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-custom-bindings

Comment: I think you're missing that in SwiftUI the `View` struct is a view model already you don't need an object. Take a look at `.task` and `.task(id:)` for fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to pass `self` and a key path to `Service`, which `Service` can then use to write to the field of `self` specified by the key path. For example, given this silly `Service`:

```
struct Service {
    let callback: (Bool) -> ()
    
    init<Object: AnyObject>(
        object: Object,
        keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Object, Bool>
    ) {
        callback = {
            object[keyPath: keyPath] = $0
        }
    }
    
    func run() {
        Task { @MainActor in
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
            callback(true)
        }
    }
}
```

We could use it like this:

```
class GenerationViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var fetching1:Bool = false
  @Published var fetching2:Bool = false
  @Published var fetching3:Bool = false

  func go() {  
    let service1 = Service(object: self, keyPath: \.fetching1)
    let service2 = Service(object: self, keyPath: \.fetching2)
    let service3 = Service(object: self, keyPath: \.fetching3)
    
    service1.run()
    service2.run()
    service3.run()
  }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant but I have to ask, is this normal to be this difficult to propagate states from network layer back to the view for SwiftUI or am I missing something?

Comment: There are no views in your question or my answer, so I don't know how to respond.